# How to edit the contents of a list?

Tags: python

How would you modify the contents of a certain position inside a list? Specifically what I need to do is to find the name of an object in a list and after that change that same exact object for another one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `index()` function and `[:]` operator for lists, as shown in the following example:

```
names = ["A", "B", "C"]
b = names.index("B")
print(b)

names[b] = "Z"
print(names)
```

Note that `index` gets the index of the first occurrence of the desired element on list.